# multiple directories for sar command

Tags: rhel, performance, load, sar

Is it normal for below directories created by `sar` command

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348948 Nov  3 23:50 sa03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348757 Nov  3 23:53 sar03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348948 Nov  4 23:50 sa04
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348757 Nov  4 23:53 sar04
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348948 Nov  5 23:50 sa05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348757 Nov  5 23:53 sar05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348948 Nov  6 23:50 sa06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348757 Nov  6 23:53 sar06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 298128 Nov  7 20:20 sa07
```

Releases are as below

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/sar
 sysstat-9.0.4-27.el6.x86_64
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
```

`cron` for `sar` entries as noticed in `/var/log/cron` as shown below

```
Nov 6 05:10:01 host-x1 CROND[13751]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Nov 6 05:20:01 host-x1 CROND[13795]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Nov 6 05:30:01 host-x1 CROND[13836]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Nov 6 05:40:01 host-x1 CROND[13882]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

I came across this reading when I was investigating abount occassional high loads on our server.